# How to protect Spring boot application with keycloak Gatekeeper?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper

I have a spring boot application and I need to protect it with the keycloak gatekeeper. Should I configure the properties file or just add the gatekeeper config file in the application? Or should I have the gatekeeper config file separately? Are there any configurations to be made in keycloak admin console?